# Javascript как создать объект из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имею такой массив:

```
[key, value, key, value, key, value]
```

Как привести к такому объекту:

```
{
key: value,
key: value,
key: value,
key: value,
key: value,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const a = ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3"];
const b = {};
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2)
  b[a[i]] = a[i + 1];
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3"];
const object = array.reduce((result, item, i, arr) => {
  return (i % 2) === 0 ? { ...result, [item]: arr[i + 1] } : result;
}, {});
console.log(object);
```